# Why does the Python Interpreter think my Int inputs are Strings?

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a program that takes sales revenue over the course of seven days and then finds the sum, average, and then highest and lowest sales. I'm stuck right now because I can't figure out how to make the interpreter take my inputs as Floats rather than strings?

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    weekly_sales_analysis()

def weekly_sales_analysis():
    sales_list = []
    sales1 = input('Enter the sales for Mon: ')
    sales_list.append(sales1)
    sales2 = input('Enter the sales for Tues: ')
    sales_list.append(sales2)
    sales3 = input('Enter the sales for Wed: ')
    sales_list.append(sales3)
    sales4 = input('Enter the sales for Thurs: ')
    sales_list.append(sales4)
    sales5 = input('Enter the sales for Friday: ')
    sales_list.append(sales5)
    sales6 = input('Enter the sales for Sat: ')
    sales_list.append(sales6)
    sales7 = input('Enter the sales for Sun: ')
    sales_list.append(sales7)

    total_sales = sum(sales_list)
    print(total_sales)

    average = sum(sales_list)/7
    print(total_weekly_sales)
```

When I run the program I get

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"
```

And whenever I try to convert clarify that the inputs are floats like this:

```
sales1 = input(float('Enter the sales for Mon: '))
```

It tells me it cannot convert strings to floats.

Comment: [`input()` returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input), that's how it was written, and you cannot change that. *"And whenever I try to convert clarify that the inputs are floats like this"* — please remember that you are dealing with a programming language, not an AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to cast the results of your `input` function to a `float` *after* it returns the value, like this:

```
sales1 = float(input('Enter the sales for Mon: '))
```

Otherwise, you're trying to cast the string `'Enter the sales for Mon: '` to a `float`, which obviously won't work - there's simply no way to interpret that value numerically.

To answer your first question, [`input` in Python 3.x takes all input as a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: I just completed it! Thank you so much.